# Objective-c load and write plist - error

Tags: objective-c, file, plist

Hi I'm practicing with plists and I learned that there are 2 different ways to load them

**FIRST METHOD:**

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documents = [path lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"]; 
self.array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

**SECOND METHOD:**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Ingredients" ofType:@"plist"];
self.array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

I don't understand clearly which way it's best... but I noticed that if I use the second one, I can't write in the plist. can anyone tell me more about it? which is the best and correct way? What's the difference?

i'm doing some tests and i have some code working only with one method...

```
//using this code the nslog will print null

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Ingredients.plist"];
    ingredients = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"ingredients:%@", self.ingredients);



//using this code the nslog will print the content of the array

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Ingredients" ofType:@"plist"];
    ingredients = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSLog(@"Authors:%@", self.ingredients);
```

Comment: 1) Where is the "error" mentioned in the title? - 2) Both methods differ only in the *location* of the plist file. People will be more happy to help if you tell *what* part of the documentation of the used methods you did not understand.

Comment: The correct way is the way that works for you and does what you want in the most affective way. So if you can't write to the plist using the second one and you want to then clearly this is not the correct way to do it and using the first way would be most affective. If you don't want to write to file then the second one would be just as affective as the first. Some developers say less code is better (This is not always the case) so if you went by this then the second would be best to use. And finally is there an actual error like the title says or is the title wrong?

Comment: error is that when i load the plist in an array and i try to print, it only gets printed with the second method, but that sucks cause i can't write in the plist this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method**

Your app only (on a non-jailbroken device) runs in a "sandboxed" environment. This means that it can only access files and directories within its own contents. For example **Documents** and **Library**.

Reference [**iOS Application Programming Guide**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html).

To access the **Documents** directory of your applications sandbox, you can use the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

This **Documents** directory allows you to store files and subdirectories your app creates or may need.

To access files in the **Library** directory of your apps sandbox use (in place of `paths`above):

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
```

**Second Method**

The Second Method is used to write the file in the **Apps main bundle.**

The main bundle is the bundle that contains the **code** and **resources** for the running application. If you are an application developer, this is the most commonly used bundle. The main bundle is also the easiest to retrieve because it does not require you to provide any information.

It is better to copy the file from **App Main Bundle** to **App Document Directory** and then use the document directories path to read/write file.

**If you are using the first method you need to copy the file from your main resources to the Documents Directory.**

Code to Copy file from app bundle to App's Document Directory

```
#define FILE_NAME @"sample.plist"

// Function to create a writable copy of the bundled file in the application Documents directory.

- (void)createCopyOfFileIfNeeded {

    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (success){
        return;
    }
    // The writable file does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:filePath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

[**Sample Code Dropbox Link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytf1g3buuvzprnn/PlistSample.zip)

Comment: ok now it's clear why the second method wont let me write... but can you please explain me why my code isn't working? i just edited my post